# How to get BCP to generate a Format File for importing fixed-width data into a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, bcp

The bcp command that I am using:

**bcp TableName format nul -c -f c:\folder\TargetFile.xml -x -S ServerName -T -q**

I think I just need the fields to have a type of *xsi:type="CharFixed"* rather then *xsi:type="CharTerm"*.

The xml that it creates which doesn't work for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="24" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="150" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="150" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t" MAX_LENGTH="20" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="12" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="UID" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="FNAME" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="LNAME" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="PHONE" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="Target" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

What I actually need: (xsi:type="CharFixed")

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="3"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharFixed" LENGTH="3"/>
</RECORD>
<ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Field1" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="3"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Field2" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" LENGTH="3"/>
</ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Comment: Can't you just edit the file that is produced so that it has what you want in it? (i.e change the generated file so that it uses CharFixed?)

Comment: Yeah. I ended up creating a c# function to build the file for me. I'm good now but tvm for getting back at me.

Comment: Oh I see, you needed to do this repeatedly for arbitrary table designs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the method I created to help me resolve my issue...

```
private XmlDocument CreateFormatFile()
    {
        const string xsiURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        var ff = new XmlDocument();
        var dec = ff.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
        ff.AppendChild(dec);
        var bcpFormat = ff.CreateElement("BCPFORMAT");
        bcpFormat.SetAttribute("xmlns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format");
        bcpFormat.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", xsiURI);
        var record = ff.CreateElement("RECORD");
        var row = ff.CreateElement("ROW");
        for (var x = 0; x < Columns.Count; x++)
        {
            var col = Columns[x];
            var id = (col.Index + 1).ToString();
            var length = col.Length.ToString();
            var column = ff.CreateElement("COLUMN");
            column.SetAttribute("SOURCE", id);
            column.SetAttribute("NAME", col.Name);
            column.SetAttribute("type", xsiURI, "SQLCHAR");
            column.SetAttribute("LENGTH", length);


            var field = ff.CreateElement("FIELD");
            field.SetAttribute("ID", id);
            if (x != Columns.Count - 1)
            {
                field.SetAttribute("type", xsiURI, "CharFixed");
                field.SetAttribute("LENGTH", length);
            }
            else
            {
                field.SetAttribute("type", xsiURI, "CharTerm");
                field.SetAttribute("TERMINATOR", @"\r\n");
            }

            record.AppendChild(field);
            row.AppendChild(column);
        }
        bcpFormat.AppendChild(record);
        bcpFormat.AppendChild(row);
        ff.AppendChild(bcpFormat);
        return ff;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [bcp Native Format Option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191232.aspx):

> **How bcp Handles Data in Native Format**
>
> ...
>
> char or varchar data
>
> At the beginning of each char or varchar field, bcp adds the prefix length.

You'd use the "-n" option instead of "-c":

**bcp TableName format nul -n -f c:\folder\TargetFile.xml -x -S ServerName -T -q**

Comment: Ok so I tried your version and I get: _xsi:type="CharPrefix"_ instead of _(xsi:type="CharFixed")_

I also get this error in SQLSERVER but I know that the fields have the exact length that the XMP depicts... 


_Msg 4866, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly._

any ideas?